# Nested loop in Assembly 8086 (

Tags: assembly, x86-16

; ( iam facing problem in printing this series 122222223222) can you plz look on code and point my mistake )

```
.model small 
.stack 100h 
.code 
start:
mov cx,3

l1:

mov ah, 02
mov dl, 49
int 21h 
inc dl

mov bx,cx
mov cx, 3

l2:

mov ah, 02
mov dl,50
int 21h 

loop l2

mov cx,bx
inc dl
loop l1

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h 

end start
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  What actually does happen when you single-step this loop?  And why are you bothering with `inc dl` if you're going to `mov dl,50` unconditionally inside the inner loop?  Is that the bug you were looking for?

Comment: yes i cant do inc dl in outer loop, which i want to do

Answer (score 3):

Your program is almost OK. The output currently is "122212221222".

That "1" character that keeps repeating, comes from the fact that you re-use the immediate value 49 **within** the loop where you should have kept this number **outside** the loop!
I suggest you store it in the `DH` register, retrieve it from there and increment `DH` on each iteration:

```
    mov  dh, "1"   ; ASCII=49
    mov  cx, 3
outerLoop:
    mov  ah, 02h
    mov  dl, dh    ; Successively "1", "2", "3"
    inc  dh
    int  21h

    mov  bx, 3
innerLoop:
    mov  ah, 02h
    mov  dl, "2"   ; ASCII=50
    int  21h 
    dec  bx
    jnz  innerLoop

    dec  cx
    jnz  outerLoop
```

Please notice that instead of using `BX` to preserve the outer loop counter, you can just as easily use `BX` as the counter for the inner loop.

For readability you can:

- use more descriptive labels
- insert blank lines to make the innner loop stand out
- write functional comments

Comment: i need to print 122222223222   (123 is outer loop and 222 is inner loop still the above program print the same series i need to do increment in outer loop which is not working properly.